# How to disable browser basic authentication popup - Angular 5 + Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, basic-authentication, angular5

I have a problem with basic authentication popup made by browser. Despite of login form in Angular, after entering credentials and clicking login button, browser creates basic authentication popup. When i log in in the browser popup, all works correctly. In each request there are these headers:

```
private createLoginHeaders(email: string, password: string): Headers {
    let headers: Headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(email + ":" + password));
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    headers.append("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

    return headers;
 }
```

And the headers are applied to this request:

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    let headers = this.createLoginHeaders(email, password);

    return this.http.post<User>(`api/user/secure/current`, {headers: headers}).do(
      (user: User) => {
        this.saveUserToLocalStorage(user);
      }
    ).catch(err => {
      if (err.status === 401) {
        return Observable.throw('Unauthorized');
      }
    });
 }
```

Do() function makes it possible to do something when i get response without changing anything in the observable. Here is the consumer method of the code above:

```
 login(email: string, password: string) {
    if(!this.authenticationService.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.authenticationService.login(email, password).subscribe(
        () => {
          this.router.navigate(['librarian']);
        }, (err) => {
          if(err === "Unauthorized") {
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
          }
        });
    }
  }
```

Here is my spring security configuration:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/**/secure/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/secure/logout")//I add '/api' to every request by setting this option in spring properties
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler())
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .httpBasic()
                .and()
                    .cors()
                .and()
                    .csrf()
                    .disable();
    }
```

Also Angular and Spring web apps are on different ports (Angular localhost:4200, Spring localhost:8080). That's why i use CORS configuration in the Spring app and proxy.conf.json in the Angular app.

Do you have any ideas? I can also show some other code snippets if it's needed. Thank you for help!

Comment: Hi, did you get it resolved? I am facing same problem.

Comment: I decided to make JSON Web Token authentication instead of this one above. Now it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you have the problem that you got a login popup when you send wrong credentials, its maybe because of your header.

Have you tried

```
headers = headers.append("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
```

append is not appending directly the header but returning a new header